# Two simple questions regarding table and PHP

Tags: php, html, sql

I have two little questions! First, some context. I have a database full of stuff about employees according to a precise month, and I need to code a simple page to print everything in a form **inside** a table. The said table (which is actually a form) displays the employee's name and the months. The content inside the months rows are **input text** (because I'll have to be able to write inside the data base from here later, **but not our problem here**).

End of context and I made a little picture.

[image]

1. How to use rowspan to get my inputs the same way they are on my picture? Every time I try, **it just mess everything up**. I'm very confused as to why.

---

**EDIT : Question 1) has been solved, I just used `<ul>` in the td**

---

2. Every single input is added thanks to my PHP script. In (very) short, it's something like this:

   foreach($employee as $emp){

   placeholder="nb">
     placeholder="nb">
    }

Their names are given according to the database, so the first input for the employee called Marc will be "Marc1" and the second one "Marc2" and so on. I don't know **how to target ONE precise input**. Anytime I try anything, my whole table is filled with the data only Marc1 should receive.

Thanks for reading guys, any help would be appreciated!

---

**EDIT : Question 2) has been solved.**

My PHP get the required data from my database then uses it for two steps:

Helping the HTML to generate an accurate form/table with the right number of inputs AND setting an id for every single input created. The said id respect the following format: userID_Month_Type.

For example, the first input text you can see in my picture would be :

(1 is Marc Id and the other 1 is the current month)

```
<input id="1_1_firstText" name="1_1_firstText" type="text">
```

This way, every sign input is easily identifiable. Here comes my JavaScript: I use split() on the id generated by PHP. I compare every part of the said id with the values gathered by PHP. If everything matches, I simply use setAttribute() to edit the value of my input. And tada.

```
<script>
var monId = "<?php echo $inputId; ?>";
var pieces = monId.split("_");
    
var month = "<?php echo $mon; ?>";
var type = "<?php echo $type; ?>";
var userId = "<?php echo $id; ?>";
var content = "<?php echo $result; ?>";
var getInput = document.getElementById(monId);

if(pieces[0] == userId && pieces[1] == month && pieces[2] == type){getInput.setAttribute('value',content);}
</script>
```

Note: Can probably be improved a lot thanks to AJAX

Comment: I'd suggest not to mess around with rowspan, but to put a `<ul>` inside the `td` and fill that with your inputs as `li`: `<td><ul><li><input 1></li><li><input 2></li></ul></td>`

Comment: @Jeff It works, and I feel dumb to not have tried that before. Thank you ! One problem is now solved

Comment: @Nawpe Did you get the answer for this?

Comment: @SandeshGupta Hello, yes my problems have been solved. Regarding the first one, I simply followed Jeff's solution to get the table I wanted. Regarding the second one, I did a little trick using PHP along Javascript. I'll edit my first message to explain the procedure. It's a bit tricky and probably dirty, but it does work without raping down the performances.